# How to download METADISE code?

Tags: software, software-assistance, solid-state-physics, metadise

I have a (possibly trivial) question regarding the METADISE code. I can find the documentation related to this code, but I cannot find the download page or tarball anywhere.

Can someone kindly share any information in this regard?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless we are both missing something obvious, it seems like there isn't a downlink available for this program online. I think the easiest way to figure out how to get this program would be to contact one of the authors (S.C.Parker@bath.ac.uk). Either direct  contact is their preferred way of distributing the program or they can tell you the best way to gain access.

Comment: I would try that. Thank you @Tyberius

Comment: After trying what Tyberius suggested, did it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The authors did not respond to my mails @NikeDattani

Answer (score 3):

Since the "Getting started" link [here](https://archive.ph/8eSOb) is broken, and neither the word "download" nor "install" appear [here](https://people.bath.ac.uk/chsscp/teach/metadise.bho/pages/metadise.html) or [here](https://people.bath.ac.uk/chsscp/group/programs/programs.html), and [this 1996 paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1996/ft/ft9969200433) about "this new computer simulation code METADISE" doesn't mention anything about the code's availability, I think it's fair to assume that this code is not available for anyone from the public to download it.

[This tutorial](https://people.bath.ac.uk/chsscp/teach/metadise.bho/pages/metadise_blog.html) which appears to be for students at the University of Bath tells students to begin by following this instruction:

> "Copy all source files of latest version from Aragonite/data2/Steve"

which suggests that even for people doing a class about METADISE, the only way (or at least, the easiest way) to obtain the software was to copy it directly from Steve Parker's folder, which would require you to have access to a very specific computer.

I agree with [the suggestion by Tyberius](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/how-to-download-metadise-code?noredirect=1#comment18952_9078) which was to contact the author directly. [Since you did that multiple times already](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/how-to-download-metadise-code?noredirect=1#comment19962_9078), you might want to see if other people who claim to have used the software (for example, the authors of [this paper](https://ceramics.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jace.14858) can shed light on how they obtained it!